# j_spring_security_check returning 404 on Tomcat but works on Jetty

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a basic Spring security setup with Form based login. When submitting my login action to j_spring_security_check it works on Jetty but fails with 404 code on Tomcat (7 & 8). I am using Spring 3.2.

So submitting to ***server:port/app/j_spring_security_check***  returns 404 response.

My security http setup looks like the following:

```
<security:http >
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
                             username-parameter="j_username"
                             password-parameter="j_password" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="springAccessManagerAuthenticationFilter"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>        
        <security:session-management></security:session-management>
        <security:headers>
            <security:cache-control/>
            <security:xss-protection/>
            <security:hsts/>
            <security:frame-options/>
            <security:content-type-options/>
        </security:headers>
    </security:http>
```

The login page looks like the following:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/tags.jsp"%>
<%@page session="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>

    <body id="login">       
        <form method="POST" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
              id="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
            Username : <input id="username" type="text" size="15" maxlength="60" name="j_username"><br><br>
            Password : <input id="password" type="password" size="15" maxlength="60" name="j_password"><br><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <input value="Login" type="submit" id="submit" name="_eventId_nextpage">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My web.xml has the **SpringSecurityFilterChain**:

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out as being a typo in web.xml on the default filter.

I had:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/j_security_check</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

`j_security_check` should have been `j_spring_security_check`